# Making a QGIS graphical Model Builder work with optional layers (advanced)

Tags: qgis, modelbuilder, gui

I am trying this for a lot of time... QGIS graphical modeler allow us to put some advanced layers, but if we use them directly in the process the modeler will crash.

I am trying to tackle this problem with the conditional branch, so I would like to put a Condition in the conditional branch for it to work only if the Advanced layer is there. And if we put none layer there the rest of the model would work but not this branch.

What condition could I put for it to see if the layer is there or no?

I have tried several ones that have not worked:

```
layer_property( @layer ,'extent')= NULL
```

[image: graphical modeler]

[image: conditional branch]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a conditional branch with `@LayerName IS NOT NULL` and the other one with `@LayerName IS NULL`.

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you so much it works

Comment: Please accept the answer! Thank you!